# Meteor "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm new to Meteor.

What I'm trying to do is send an email to someone when they are invited to join the service (done) but I want that email to dynamically be populated with the user who invited them to join's details. This is the code I have:

```
    Meteor.publish('profile', function() {
        return Meteor.users.find(this.userId);
    });



    var emailData = {
        existingUser: 'currentUser().profile.displayName',
        existingOrganisation: 'currentUser().profile.organisation',
        existingEmail: Meteor.users.emails[0].address
    };

    //Code taken from Meteor Docs to customise content of enrollment email
    Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = "Amendd";
    Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "Amendd <no-reply@amendd.com>";
    Accounts.emailTemplates.enrollAccount.subject = function (user) {
        return "Welcome to Amendd";
    };
    Accounts.emailTemplates.enrollAccount.html = function (user, url) {
        return  SSR.render('enrollAccountEmail', emailData) + url;
    };
```

Where enrollAccount.html is a seperate file in my '/private' folder. I have put the ' -- ' in place after my existingUser and existingOrganisation variables, while I focus on getting the email field to work.

The error message that I'm getting thrown up when I save and run the project in Terminal is

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

where it points me to the [0] in the existingEmail variable.

Can anyone shed any light on the issue I'm having?

**UPDATE**

The fix for this was moving the emailData object within the function:

```
            SSR.compileTemplate('enrollAccountEmail', Assets.getText('enrollAccountEmail.html'));
            Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = "Amendd";
            Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "Amendd <no-reply@amendd.com>";
            Accounts.emailTemplates.enrollAccount.subject = function (user) {
                return "Welcome to Amendd , " + user.email;
            };
            Accounts.emailTemplates.enrollAccount.html = function (user, url) {
            var emailData = {
                existingUser: Meteor.user().profile.displayName,
                existingOrganisation: Meteor.user().profile.organisation,
                existingEmail: Meteor.user().emails[0].address
            };

                return  SSR.render('enrollAccountEmail', emailData) + url;
            };
```

Comment: The error is saying that Meteor.users.emails is undefined. Make sure you have this field in your database or any other data provider. Why are getting existingUser for example differently from existingEmail?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `currentUser().emails[0].address`?

Comment: I originally tried currentUser().emails[0].address and that threw up the error "ReferenceError: currentUser is not defined", the reason existingUser and existingOrganisation are still like that is because I dropped a quote either side to see whether I could pull any data through using SSR (which it does)

Comment: How do you get the referrer's email address/user id? Is it stored somewhere? And why are you constructing the `emailData` object outside of the function?

Comment: The referrer's email address is the one they have registered with when they created an account, stored with the Meteor accounts package. I'm having no issue returning this information on the client side, it's just on the server side.  My mistake on the placing of the emailData object, I've moved it within the function now, but still getting the same error.

Comment: How does `Meteor.users.emails[0].address` know what user you are referring to? This should be `Meteor.users.findOne({some:identifier}).emails[0].address` becaue Meteor.users is a collection and like any other collection you need to query a specific value from it, in this case using findOne to ensure it returns an object you can look things up in.

Also just as an aside, using user profile for storing data like username is bad practice unless you have deny rules on your profile as this is openly accessible and modifiable by default for all users (the rest of user object is secure though)

Comment: @PhilipPryde Could you elaborate sorry, I'm very new to Meteor.  I have changed it to `existingEmail: Meteor.users.findOne({'this.UserID':_id}).emails[0].address` and now I have the terminal error `ReferenceError: _id is not defined`  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Almost you would want to use _id:this.userId though without the quotes and the other way round. Is that call in a method in the server? If you can provide a github repo example id be happy to take a peek and provide a fix there

Comment: @PhilipPryde That would be really helpful thanks, I've just published it to https://github.com/lxjffrs/Amendd, the file I'm working on is /server/invitedUserSignupServer.js

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe currentUser() works on the server. Try using Meteor.user(), it will work anywhere but a publish function.

Meteor.user().emails[0].address

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user

Comment: Thanks Sam! That's done the job - I had tried this before but I was defining the emailData object outside of the function